# Upgrade to version 4.7.31 seems to have broken DAO.PHP

Tags: cron-job, cron

Version 4.7.31 was installed and now an hourly cron job is erroring like this:

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /.../administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php on line 651.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you perhaps aren't using a supported version of PHP.  I would check your version; my guess is that you're on PHP 5.4, since 5.5 is the minimum supported version in Civi 4.7.31.

I would restore your site from a backup if you're not in a position to upgrade PHP immediately - but my advice is to try to upgrade PHP.  PHP 5.4 is known to be insecure and hasn't received security updates in [almost 3 years](http://php.net/supported-versions.php).